# Fatal error: Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sample\testdb.php

Tags: php, mongodb

Fatal error:

> Class 'Mongo' not found in C:\Apache
>   Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\sample\testdb.php

Can anyone help me out with this issue? Why is that saying so?

The following is the code that I have used. I have created a database named `phptest` in MongoDB and inserted a document. Then I tried connecting to MongoDB via PHP but it threw this error.

Can anyone help me get rid of this? I have included the php-mongo dll and saved in php.ini file also.

```
<?php
echo "succeeded!";
$connection = new Mongo();
$db = $connection->test;
$collection = $db->phptest;
?>
```

Comment: This question belongs on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct php driver installed.

For example if "Thread Safety" is enabled in your php.ini, then make sure you have the "Thread-Safe Mongo Extension" installed and NOT the "Non-Thread-Safe" version.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using an older version of the Mongo DB driver. The class `Mongo` has been replaced with `MongoClient`, since v 1.3.0 of the driver. See this stackoverflow thread :

1. [mongo DB - php driver version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722594/mongo-db-php-driver-version/14723957#14723957)
2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongo.php