# mongo DB - php driver version

Tags: php, mongodb, driver, database

I am using XAMPP, PHP Version 5.3.5.

I installed mongodb.

I tried to connect mongo db from my php code, it gives me error

```
$connection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
$db = $connection->dbname;

echo $db;
```

`Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 9`

I guess it is because, I installed a old version of php-mongo driver.

What is the proper version of php-mongo driver for PHP Version 5.3.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of the MongoDB driver for PHP is 1.3.4.

The class `Mongo` was deprecated with version 1.3 and replaced with `MongoClient`. Apparently you are using an older version than 1.3 in your install.

http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo

Comment: Apparently the latest stable version for Windows versions is still 1.3.1, which you can download [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads)

They don't seem to be that keen on being up-to-date. It does contain `MongoClient` already though, since I'm still using that version

Comment: Thank you , let me go through it :)